# How to enable mobile number based authentication in rails API project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise, sms, omniauth

I would prefer to use an omniauth based solution, where the OTP of the mobile phone number is sent via SMS for authentication purposes.

I need mobile number authentication too, I looked into [active_model_otp](https://github.com/heapsource/active_model_otp) but its supports 2FA using Google authenticator but I want SMS feature, what is the best way to support that?